# why can't I insert data into tables I created in sql server managment studio 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the tables with this:

```
CREATE TABLE COSTUMER(
    COSTUMER_ID INT,
    TAXI_ID INT,
    COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER INT,
    COSTUMER_NAME VARCHAR(40)
    DESTINATION VARCHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE TAXI(
    TAXI_ID INT,
    COSTUMER_ID INT,
    TAXI_REGISTRATION_NUMBER INT,
    TAXI_PHONE_NUMBER INT,
    DRIVER_NAME INT,
    DESTINATION
);

CREATE TABLE BOOKING(
    DESTINATION VARCHAR(40),
    TAXI_ID INT,
    COSTUMER_ID,
    COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER INT,
    DRIVER_PHONE_NUMBER INT,
    TAXI_REGISTRATION_NUMBER INT,
    TAXI_NAME VARCHAR(40)
    COSTUMER_NAME VARCHAR(40)
    TIME_OF_ARRIVAL DATETIME,
);
```

After this my table appeared with all the attributes. Then I set my PKs and FKs manually.

now am trying to insert some data to each of the tables but I keep getting error 213:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

I searched and searched and still don't understand.

also when I insert the code for such as `SELECT * FROM Costumer` (that's the table name) it won't show in the small suggestion box as if it doesn't exist???

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are **not** the same thing.

Comment: post your insert query here so that some one can help you

Comment: I think the SQL Server Management Studio in the title gives it away...

Comment: This error is becuase the values which you are trying to insert either are more than total columns in table or less than the total number of columnsin table. It's also possible you are trying to insert an incompatible data-type in some column. PLease post your insert script.

Comment: POst your columns instead of select *

Comment: @user3847554 One suggestion, Correct the spelling `COSTUMER` to `CUSTOMER`

Comment: @jesuraja corrected the spelling and now facing error 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int" stuck! X_X

Comment: @GREPCODE INSERT INTO COSTUMER (COSTUMER_ID, TAXI_ID, COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER, COSTUMER_NAME, DESTINATION) values (1, 32, 07854625781, 'Denzel Washington', 'Heathrow Airport'

Comment: you are not closing the final brace ')' or you just missed it here? @user3847554

Comment: The value 07854625781 is too big to handle for int type

Comment: @user3847554 : Please have a look at my answer posted below and let us know if it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should work for your requirement unless you have specified an identity column manually as you said that you made some changes manually.

In case you specified an identity column manually then you should not insert the value for the Identity column (say Customer_ID) or you should set SET IDENTITY_INSERT COSTUMER ON before inserting the ID column

```
CREATE TABLE COSTUMER(
    COSTUMER_ID INT,
    TAXI_ID INT,
    COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER INT,
    COSTUMER_NAME VARCHAR(40),
    DESTINATION VARCHAR(40)
);
SELECT * FROM COSTUMER


INSERT INTO COSTUMER (COSTUMER_ID, TAXI_ID,COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER,COSTUMER_NAME,DESTINATION) VALUES (1, 33,123211241, 'John','Mexico' )
```

Comment: I have tried the above suggestion                                                                                                                              insert into COSTUMER (COSTUMER_ID, TAXI_ID, COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER, COSTUMER_NAME, DESTINATION)
values
(1, 32, 07854625781, 'Denzel Washington', 'Heathrow Airport') however I keep getting error 8115 "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.              thanks for the help peeps :)

Comment: message 8115 level 16, state 2, line 1

Comment: That is because you are making the COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER as INT and trying to insert a number as big as 07854625781. Make COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER AS BIGINT while creating the table, then it should work

Comment: Phonenumbers are strings, not integral numbers. Use a varchar of sufficient size, not a numerical type.

Answer (score 0):

Post the insert statement you used. I see a few problems with the current code you posted.

You don't provide datatypes for a few of your attributes, for instance in the Booking table you need to provide some type for the CUSTOMER_ID attribute. Also you need the attributes and datatypes to be comma separated, except the last one doesn't need a trailing comma. For instance you have:

```
  ...
  TAXI_REGISTRATION_NUMBER INT,
  TAXI_NAME VARCHAR(40)
  COSTUMER_NAME VARCHAR(40)
  TIME_OF_ARRIVAL DATETIME, 
  ...
```

This will throw an error probably saying incorrect syntax near COSTUMER_NAME.

You need something like:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING(
    DESTINATION VARCHAR(40),
    TAXI_ID INT,
    COSTUMER_ID INT,
    COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER INT,
    DRIVER_PHONE_NUMBER INT,
    TAXI_REGISTRATION_NUMBER INT,
    TAXI_NAME VARCHAR(40),
    COSTUMER_NAME VARCHAR(40),
    TIME_OF_ARRIVAL DATETIME
);
```

For an insert try something along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (<column1>,<column2>,<column3>)
VALUES (<col1Value>,<col2Value>,<col3Value>)
```

If you aren't getting auto completion you might try and refresh the DB in the management studio by `right click > refresh`, but I wouldn't rely on auto completion at all in SQL Server nor IntelliSense unless you use someting like [this](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/).

If you post the insertion script I might be able to help more.

Update: So, the problem you got was with arithmetic overflow, specifically trying to put 07854625781 into a int. All datatypes have maximum/minimums or other "constraints", an int can be in the range of `-2^31 (-2,147,483,648)` through `2^31 - 1 (2,147,483,647)` (4 bytes). The value you enter exceeds that, it is being interpreted as 07,854,625,781 (7.8 billion) while the maximum for an int is only 2.147 billion. If you change the datatype of phone number to bigint that can hold `-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808)` through `2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)` (8 bytes) it will work, However I would advise you not to store a phone number in that way, rather, use char(length) if you know that the size and format will always be the same, if you think the length could vary (maybe from extensions or international numbers) I would use something along the lines of varchar(40).

Through this datatype change you will just have to surround input in 'single quotes' when you insert.

Cheers

Comment: I have tried the above suggestion insert into COSTUMER (COSTUMER_ID, TAXI_ID, COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER, COSTUMER_NAME, DESTINATION) values (1, 32, 07854625781, 'Denzel Washington', 'Heathrow Airport') however I keep getting error 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int" how can I get rid of this and why is it appearing. thanks

Comment: Ah! I see the problem! I'll update my answer :)

Comment: Pretty much you were trying to insert 7.something billion into a space that can only hold 2.147 billion. Have a good one, cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to insert more/less input to table

> INSERT INTO [TableName] **(Column1, Column2, Column3)**
>   VALUES **(Value1, Value2, Value3)**

Number of columns should be equal to Number of Values. Please check your `INSERT` statement.
If you not included **`(Column1, Column2, Column3)`** in your statement, include it.

Comment: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. keeps appearing when I execute any ideas to why?. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Problem that you are facing in the below  insert  query is  the value 07854625781 has become too large to handle for int type. Int range 2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647). So change the datatype of COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER to Bigint.

```
 INSERT INTO COSTUMER (COSTUMER_ID, TAXI_ID, COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER, COSTUMER_NAME, DESTINATION) values (1, 32, 07854625781, 'Denzel Washington', 'Heathrow Airport')
```

use the below query to change the datatype to bigint and then try insert(above command)

```
     ALTER TABLE COSTUMER ALTER COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER bigint;
```

Steps to Follow

```
   ALTER TABLE COSTUMER ALTER COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER bigint;
    INSERT INTO COSTUMER (COSTUMER_ID, TAXI_ID, COSTUMER_PHONE_NUMBER, COSTUMER_NAME, DESTINATION) values (1, 32, 07854625781, 'Denzel Washington', 'Heathrow Airport');
```

Now do

```
   Select * from COSTUMER
```

you will find the record inserted

Comment: Thank you ever so much! it finally worked everything is in order

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct if it has helped you. Upvoting is always encouraged. @user3847554